# Swipe gesture on google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, swipe, gesture

I'm trying to add swipe gesture on a basic application which just show a google map. It works fine without map. Here is my solution without the map :

```
private float x1,x2;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
private Point pt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pt = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(pt);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{     
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          if(event.getX()>pt.x-5){
              x1 = event.getX();  
              Log.d("DEBUUUUG", ""+event.getX());
          }else{
              x1=0;
          }
      break;         
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          if(x1>=pt.x-5){
              x2 = event.getX();
              Log.d("DEBUUUUG", "X1="+x1+" X2="+x2);
              float deltaX = x2 - x1;
              if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
              {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
              }
          }
      break;   
    }           
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);    
}
```

and here is my xml layout with the map (the layout without just has a simple LinearLayout who's empty) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapSee"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

My goal is to add a right-to-left slider, like on the GoogleMaps app.
Is it possible ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Done, I've found a solution. I don't think it's the best way to do this, but it works.
I've added an invisible button :

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_slideMenuCM"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've implemented a TouchListener on this button :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    //The action to do
        break;
}
return false;
}
```

It's not a real "swipe gesture", but it looks like.

Comment: Use `NavigationDrawer`. Works like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.demo (source on GitHub)

Comment: Thanks Maciej. The thing is that I already use a lib for right/left panel : `simple-side-drawer` https://github.com/adamrocker/simple-side-drawer on other screens. So I would like to reuse this lib...